# Rails sql issue with a simple where statement

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get a very simple statement working.

```
Node.where("nodeid = ?", nstart).select('id')
```

Results in

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WpSpzLzaFUx8QgFbwEfygQUkkqvbUgZl8Hh0UxJvT8E=", "edge"=>{"kind"=>"IsA", "start_id"=>"blabla", "end_id"=>"bliblib", "property1"=>"bloblbo"}, "commit"=>"Create Edge"}
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Node Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
```

It should be just a ´select nodes.id from nodes where nodeid = blabla´ The limit doesn't matter.

However if I add .first.

```
Node.where("nodeid = ?", nstart).select('id').first
```

I get

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WpSpzLzaFUx8QgFbwEfygQUkkqvbUgZl8Hh0UxJvT8E=", "edge"=>{"kind"=>"IsA", "start_id"=>"blabla", "end_id"=>"bliblib", "property1"=>"bloblbo"}, "commit"=>"Create Edge"}
  Node Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "nodes"."id" FROM "nodes"  WHERE (nodeid = 'blabla')  ORDER BY "nodes"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Node Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "nodes"."id" FROM "nodes"  WHERE (nodeid = 'bliblib')  ORDER BY "nodes"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Node Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

The first select now is what it should be but the follow up is again like before and seems to determine the eventual return value (because it doesn't work either). I just want the id when I only know the nodeid which basically is the name of the node.

What is going on in Rails here?

Comment: I really doubt the first output and I think you gave wrong output, I don't see any relation with the code `Node.where("nodeid = ?", nstart).select('id')`

Comment: Yes but I triple checked. It must be some caching problem. I tried changing the values each time and restarting the server. Now I get the correct stmt with the first solution but it returns a Node object. I seem to need the first too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the `id` value you could do this

```
Node.where("nodeid = ?", nstart).limit(1).pluck(:id).first
```

This would return 1 integer with the value

**EDIT**:

ok scratch that, i guess you don't really need to use `limit` so a simple `first` would just do

```
Node.where("nodeid = ?", nstart).first[:id]
```

or

```
Node.where("nodeid = ?", nstart).first.id
```

Comment: `limit(1)` and `first` seem to do the same things. But since `limit(1)` still should return a collection of values (if not called with 1), whereas `first` only one: `limit(1)` shouldn't be there.

Comment: well I just double checked, I guess first does add limit by it self

Comment: It does not work though. .first['id'] does the same as my first without any parameters. ´SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE (nodeid = 'Rails')  ORDER BY "nodes"."id" ASC LIMIT 1´ It does not even pick the id but * and I still don't understand what the follow up transaction is. Edge.new should not cause a transaction on the node table at all.

Comment: well I don't understand, I write the same query on my app and it does a `select id` query, not `select *`, what you have in your question should run correctly

Comment: I don't understand it either. I managed to get this far.
Node Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "nodes"."id" FROM "nodes"  WHERE (nodeid = 'x1') LIMIT 1
#<Node:0x007fc79faeb640>
But the return is some object instead of the actual id integer value. Any Ideas? It uses no first or limit just select('id'), with first I always get the weird stuff where it doesn't select on the id in the stmt at all.

Comment: Returning an object is the correct behaviour, it returns an object but only fills the attributes you selected, if for example `node` has a `name` doing a `node.name` should throw a missing attribute error, and doing `node.id` would return the correct value.

Comment: I think I worked it out. The first query works because I get the correct integers but there is a validation problem afterwards. Must be validation existence that does not work as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a query:

```
Node.where("nodeid = ?", nstart).select('id')
```

will return an array of objects (or empty array if there's no suitable records) *not array actually. Activerecord::Relation

If you use 'first' like Mohammad AbuShady told:

```
Node.where("nodeid = ?", nstart).select('id').first
```

you get an object (or nil if there's no record)

If you want an integer id value, you can get it from the object

```
Node.where("nodeid = ?", nstart).first.id
```

select('id') tells active record not to retrieve all the fields in the table, just 'id'